# Create graph in Excel similar to panelled SPSS "simple error bar" plot

Tags: excel, graph, charts, spss

I created a graph in SPSS [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IOQ9.png) that I want to be able to recreate in Excel, but I don't know how.

I want to be able to represent dots that represent the mean value for lots of different measures (sample picture just shows 4, in reality I have several more), where all those means are shown on the same axis, ideally with 95% error bars for the means as well. In addition, I want to panel the graph to show the same thing for different cases (ie. the variable named 'Entity') side by side.

In SPSS, I did this by creating what it calls a 'simple error bar' plot in the Chart Builder, dragging all the measures I want to include to the y-axis, adding a 'column panel zone' with the variable Entity, and then finally transposing the graph to flip the y and x axes.

I would like to recreate a similar graph in Excel, however, as these graphs are better quality and also much easier to come back to edit later on as necessary.

I have all of the relevant values (means and lower/upper bounds of the confidence intervals for different measures according to Entity) copied into tables in Excel, but I have been completely stumped trying to figure out how to recreate a similar graph, nothing I've tried seems to produce anything similar; I can't even seem to produce something that looks like just one of the panels, with the values for multiple measures represented as different dots on the same axis.

I've tried several things - different permutations of the tables in Excel, and different 'graph' options. [Attached is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99s9G.png) with the closest I've gotten - I insert a 'line with markers' chart and then make the line white so it disappears, and manually add error bars using 'add chart element --> error bars' and then 'format error bars --> custom --> specify value'. The markers and error bars look good, but the problem is that the listing of the different measures is horizontal across the different entity categories, instead of one being panelled horizontally and the other listed vertically as in the SPSS version; another issue is that it produces one master value axis instead of recreating the axis for multiple panels.

Does anyone have any guidance here or can point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate it!